# R# identation based on previous automatically aligned line

Tags: c#, resharper

I am trying to configure R# with VS 2019 for the first time and I'm wondering if a specific indentation is possible to do.

What I currently have :

[image: indent I currently have]

I would like to move the 3rd line (and if possible the closing parenthese at 4th line) to be indented to the beginning of the previous line which is aligned, like this :

[image]

Here are my **Parenthesis** options *(Extension / Resharper / Options / Code Editing / C# / Formatting Style / Tabs, Indent, Alignment)* :

[image]

And here are my **Align multiline constructs** options *(Extension / Resharper / Options / Code Editing / C# / Formatting Style / Tabs, Indent, Alignment)*

[image]

Is what I want to do even possible with the current indentation options available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no  you can align arguments to the enclosing parenthesis, e. g.:

```cs
worksheet.Cells[positionExcelLine, 4]
         .Value = Convert.ToDecimal(
                                    total["MONTANT"].Replace(" ", "");
```

For this, go to *ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Tabs, Indents, Alignment* and enable *Call arguments by '('`*:
[image]

Comment: That is not really what I wanted so I'm not closing the question with your answer, but this is clearly better than what I had! Thank you for your time and help :)